# c++ bit operations how to print out 16, 32 bits

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

at the moment I have script which prints out numeric values into bits so for example

```
print((short) 1);
```

I get a value of `00000001`, but how can I get for this a value like `00000001 00000000` and in case if I print `print((int) 1);` I get a value of `00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000`.
Here is my code:

```
void printbyte(unsigned char x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (x & 0x80) cout << 1;
        else cout << 0;
        x = x << 1;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void print (T A)
{
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) &A;
    printbyte(*p);
}

int main()
{
    print((short) 1);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printbyte` cannot print `00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000`. It prints ONLY 8 BITS.

Comment: Replace `8` with `sizeof(x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `sizeof(T)` within `print` to determine how many bytes to process and then call `printbyte` for each byte, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

void printbyte(unsigned char x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++)
    {
        cout << ((x & 0x80) != 0);
        x <<= 1;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void print (T A)
{    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T); ++i)
    {
        unsigned char b = A >> ((sizeof(T) - i - 1) * CHAR_BIT);
        //unsigned char b = A >> (i * CHAR_BIT); // use this for little endian output
        printbyte(b);
        cout << " ";   
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    print((short) 1);
    print((long long) 42);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks very ok, but with instead of `00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000` it shows `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001`, is it possible to change correctly? Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Well it would be very easy to reverse the order of the loop, but I think it would be rather confusing to print the value in a little endian format like that. If that's what you want though then just change `unsigned char b = A >> ((sizeof(T) - i - 1) * CHAR_BIT);` to `unsigned char b = A >> (i * CHAR_BIT);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitset, it's the easiest way. Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
 int number;
 cin>>number;
 bitset <16> end (number);
 cout<<number<<" --> "<<end<<'\n';
 return 0;
}
```

Or reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/

If you not want to use standard solutions, it can also look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

template <typename Type>
void bprint(Type in)
 {
  unsigned char* p = (reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&in))+(sizeof(Type)-1); //x86
  for(unsigned int n = sizeof(Type);n--;--p, std::cout<<' ')
   for(unsigned int i = CHAR_BIT;i--;)
    std::cout<<((*p&char(1<<i))!=0);
  std::cout<<'\n';
 }

int main(void)
{
 int number;
 cin>>number;
 bprint(number);
 bprint(short(number));
 bprint(char(number));
return 0;
}
```

"unsigned" before "char*" is required, if it isn't set by default. Access to variable's memory has only a pointer of variable's type or unsigned char, according to standard.

The most interesting option is the use of mathematics, described, inter alia, by Gynvael Coldwind, here: http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/n/c_cpp_number_to_binary_string_01011010 .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/), but you always have to specify the size at compile time.
To avoid that, you can use a template function like this (note that this is C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <limits>

template <class T> void PrintBits (const T &Number) {
    std::bitset<std::numeric_limits<T>::digits> Bit_Number(Number);
    std::cout << Bit_Number << std::endl;

}
```